# Django admin password Changed Spontaneously

Tags: django, django-admin

Something bizarre happened. I'm developing locally and I had my admin superuser account working for quite a while.

I recently just messed around with the decorators module in Django, but I ultimately didn't add any code there (i did add some, but I then deleted all of it).

Now, my admin is no longer recognizing my password.  I am 100% certain that the password is correct.

I am receiving a traceback within my development server which claims that it's a Sockets error.

```
C:\Python27\lib\socket.py, line 303

error: an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Any clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

No idea why that might have happened, from what you've said.  But if you need to reset your admin password, you can do it like this:

From shell:

```
python ./manage.py shell
```

In python:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> users
[<User: admin>, etc...]
>>> user = users[0] # 0 being the index of the User account you want,
                    # returned on the previous line
>>> user.set_password('newpass');
>>> user.save()
```

Comment: I just ended up deleting the database and using syncdb to create a new superuser.

Comment: I'm more concerned about pushing this to my remote server and somehow corrupting my superuser.  I don't understand how this happened and why I was having socket errors

Comment: Well it obviously shouldn't happen normally -- and I can only guess that it's something in your code that's causing it.  The guys at irc://irc.freenode.net/django might be able to help you track this one down, as there are usually a few people on there who know django's internals really well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of django, what happens if you try to change your admin password from manage.py?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#django-admin-changepassword